# How to update jsonb column array in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using Postgres, I have a "Disparos" table. It has a 'contacts' jsonb column with an array de objects. I can have many objects  into array, not only 2.

Something as:

```
contacts:[
  {
    "ack": "0",
    "nome": "        Maria Jose",
    "email": "cprado@gmail.com",
    "start": "2024-01-14T14:52:35.980Z",
    "numero": "5521984470087",
    "messageId": "1",
    "timestamp": 1705243836125
  },
  {
    "ack": "0",
    "nome": "        Maria Jose",
    "email": "cprado@gmail.com",
    "start": "2024-01-14T14:52:35.980Z",
    "numero": "5521984470087",
    "messageId": "",
    "timestamp": 1705243836125
  }]
```

I need update "ack" to 1 and "timestamp" to 1705341218404 if "messageId" obeys a condition.
I tried the next, but no look. What am I doing wrong:

```
UPDATE "Disparos"
SET contacts = jsonb_set(
    contacts, 
    '{1}', 
    jsonb_set(
        contacts->1,
        '{ack}', 
        '1'::jsonb
    ) || jsonb_set(
        contacts->1, 
        '{timestamp}', 
        '1705341218404'::jsonb
    )
)
WHERE 
    contacts->>'messageId'='1'
```

Comment: What happends if you run your qeury?

Comment: It returns:
UPDATE 0

Query returned successfully in 216 msec.

Comment: Have you tried the select the row? For me it looks like the record is not found.

Answer (score 0):

Looke like your UPDATE statement has some issues, you cannot use array index directly in jsonb_set function. Also, you cannot use WHERE condition on jsonb array elements directly. You need to use jsonb_array_elements_text function with a subquery.

Try Below Query

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT id, jsonb_set(elem::jsonb, '{ack}', '"1"')::jsonb || jsonb_set(elem::jsonb, '{timestamp}', '"1705341218404"')::jsonb new_elem
  FROM (
    SELECT id, jsonb_array_elements_text(contacts) elem
    FROM "Disparos"
  ) sub
  WHERE (elem::jsonb ->> 'messageId') = '1'
)
UPDATE "Disparos" d
SET contacts = jsonb_set(contacts, ('{' || idx - 1 || '}')::text[], cte.new_elem)
FROM (
  SELECT id, row_number() OVER () AS idx
  FROM cte
) sub
WHERE d.id = sub.id;
```